# How can I access an element by using its DOM hierarchy(parent element)?

Tags: html, dom, testing, selenium, automation

I want to access an element using a DOM hierarchy Node structure, through its parent nodes.I am trying to find the DOM hierarchy through firebug; want something like, `<parent_node1>.<child_node1>.<child_node2>` (**not by** `document.getElementByID`, `getElementbyname`) to access an element.

I want to automate a scenario like, I have column headers and corresponding values. Want to test, whether the values present under each column header, is correct...

I am thinking of using DOM as a method of automating this case...But, how can I find the DOM hierarchy...?

What I see through Inspect Element in Firebug is something like, list of events, elements and is not looking like a hierarchy node structure...Can somebody help in this regard please?

Comment: Do you mean the `element.childNodes` collection, `element.firstChild` or similar? http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml

Comment: @TorstenWalter thanks! The link was pretty much helpful...In fact, as the issue is dealing with table contents...Getting the rows, through rows[] function will be helpful...Can you provide that as the answer, with an example..!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, you probably mean the `DOM Element properties` like  `element.childNodes`, `element.firstChild` or similar.

Have a look at the [DOM Element property reference over at JavaScriptKit](http://javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml), you'll get a good overview there how to access the hierarchy.

```
var currentTD = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
var currentTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

currentTD.parentNode // contains the TR element the TD resides in.
currentTable.childNodes // contains THEAD TBODY and TFOOT if present.
```

[DOM Tables even have more properties](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/tableproperties.shtml) like a `rows` collection and a `cells` collection.

**A reminder of caution**: Beware that these collections are live collections, so iterating over them and accessing `collection.length` in each iteration can be really slow because to get the length, the DOM has to be queried each time.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` and `document.getElementByTagname` **are** using the DOM. They take an object within the DOM (specifically the document object, though you can also call both of those on elements) and return an object which is a single element or a collection of zero or more elements, respectively. That's a DOM operation. From there you can do other DOM operations on the results like getting children, parents or siblings, changing values etc.

All DOM operations come down to:

1. Take a starting point. This is often `document` though it's so often that the first thing we do is call `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementByTagname` and then work from the result that we could really consider that the starting point.
2. Find the element or elements we are interested in, relative to the starting point whether through `startingPoint.getElementById`* or `startingPoing.getElementByTagname` perhaps combined with some test (e.g. only working on those with a particular `classname`, if they have children of particular types, etc.
3. Read and/or change certain values, add new child nodes and/or delete nodes.

In a case like yours the starting point will be one or more tables found by `document.getElementById(someID)`, `document.getElementById(someID).getElementsByTagname('table')[0]`, or similar. From that table, `myTable.getElementsByTagname('th')` will get you the column headings. Depending on the structure, and what you are doing with it, you could just select corresponding elements from `myTable.getElementsByTagname('td')` or go through each row and then work on `curRow.getElementsByTagname('td')`.
You could also just use `firstChild`, `childNodes` etc. though it's normally more convenient to have elements you don't care about filtered out by tagname.

*Since there can only be one element with a given id in a document, this will return the same if called on any element higher in the document hierarchy, so we normally just call this on `document`. It can be useful to call it on an element if we want to do something if the element is a descendant of our current element, and not otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Jon!:) Your answer is very detailed and very helpful...!:)I sincerely thank and appreciate your help